# How DO I solve - Error Number: 1054 Unknow Column CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

According to the CI [documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/pagination.html#setting-preferences-in-a-config-file), I follow and implement pagination but I can't get this to work.

```
A Database Error Occurred 
Error Number: 1054 
Unknown column '2' in 'order clause' 
SELECT * FROM (`asst_vendor`) ORDER BY `2` LIMIT 10 
Filename: ...\system\database\DB_driver.php
Line Number: 330
```

Everything works as expected for page 1, but when I'm visiting page 2 I faced the above error.
I think something is wrong in model line no.13 **$rs=$query->result_array();** Am I failing to load something?

here is my code
**Model**

```
public function getVendor($offset,$page,$sorting,$order)
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('asst_vendor');
        $this->db->limit($page,$offset);
        if($sorting!="")
        {
            $this->db->order_by($sorting,$order);
        }
        $query=$this->db->get();
        // var_dump($query->result_array());
        $rs=$query->result_array();
        return $rs;
    }
```

**Controller**

```
function getVendor()
    {
        $sorting = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $order = $this->uri->segment(4);
        
        $config = array();
            $config["base_url"] =   site_url("vendor/getVendor").'/'.$sorting.'/'.$order;;
            $config['page_query_string'] = FALSE;

            $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
            $config["per_page"] = 10;
            $page_number = $this->uri->segment(5);
            if(empty($page_number)) $page_number = 1;
            $offset = ($page_number-1) * $config['per_page'];
            
            $tvendor=$this->vendor_model->getcountVendor();
            $config["total_rows"]=$tvendor[0]['total_vendor'];
            $choice = $config["total_rows"] / $config['per_page'];
            $config["num_links"] = round($choice);
            $config["enable_query_strings"] = FALSE;
            $config['uri_segment']=5;
            $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div align="center"><ul class="pagination">';
            $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul></div><!--pagination-->'; 

            $config['first_link'] = '&laquo; First';
            $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
            $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
            $config['last_link'] = 'Last &raquo;';
            $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li >';
            $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
            $config['next_link'] = '&gt;';
            $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
            $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
            $config['prev_link'] = '&lt;';
            $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li>';
            $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
            $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="">';
            $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
            $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li class="page">';
            $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>'; 
            $this->pagination->cur_page = $offset;
            $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        
        $temp['link']=$this->pagination->create_links();
        $temp['vendor']=$this->vendor_model->getVendor($offset,$config["per_page"],$sorting,$order);
        $this->load->view('vendoroverview',$temp);
    }
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Order By should use a column name. It looks like you're passing in the page number instead.

Comment: @aynber I'm new to Codeigniter, could you please add some example as how I used paginating instead of the column name

Comment: Paginating uses limit/offset, with `$this->db->limit($page,$offset);`. Order By sorts the results by the selected column. I have not touched CodeIgniter in years so couldn't tell you exactly how the pagination parameters are passed, but mysql queries use `LIMIT (X number of rows) OFFSET (Y number of results). See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html for examples.